# iPhone personalized table Rounded corner table

Tags: iphone, uitableview, iphone-sdk-4.3

I don't have too much experience on iphone screen designs but I need to make a table like this: (image), I made an investigation but I didn't find anything. This table needs to have a rounded corner and the user will be able to insert data, in this case first name, last name, etc...
Right now I'm using SDK 4.3. if someone have an tutorial I would appreciate

Thank you,

[image: editable rounded corner table]

Comment: Hey, the table has rounded corners as it is a grouped table, check Interface Builder and there is an option for it to be grouped in the tables properties. You then have to implement UITableViews delegate methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can customize table border. 
All you need to do is import QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h file.

and set following properties in viewDidLoad

```
tableView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0f;
tableView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
tableView.layer.borderWidth = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

- The first google [result](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html) for `custom uitableview` does something alike, hard to customize and not very flexible, but it looks very pretty and saves a lot of drawing-implementation time (you can override `drawRect` for the custom appearance).
- For the more reusable solution with several controls over the cell you can subclass `UITableViewCell`, add and stylize the subviews as you need (title labels, textviews, dividers), override `layoutSubviews`. You'll probably want to add the editing listeners to animate the `textViews` getting larger and the divider moving aside. That general solution works for any UI control (e.g. you can quickly make a checkbox with a button) and the approach.